# why json return data is showing [] (third bracket) in ajax success method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am validating a form using jQuery / Ajax method.

Bellow is my jQuery code and I am passing `json` data type. But in `ajax` `success` method it's return any data with **third braket** like : **[my return data]**

**jQuery Code :**

```
$("#filter_c_n").change(function() {    
    var data = $("#filter_c_n").val();
    $.ajax({
        url : 'search_c_n.php',
        method : 'POST',        
        data : {
            key : data  
        },
        datatype : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            $("#filter_c_n_result").html(data);
        }
    });             
});
```

Here is my php file which contain bellow code :

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once("corefile.php");
user_login_check();
timeout();

$data =  array();
$key =  inputvalid($_POST['key']);
$data['key'] = $key;
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

What is showing is bellow :

[image]

Comment: As you are returning an array use index i.e. `$("#filter_c_n_result").html(data[0]);`

Comment: *Third* bracket? I only see two in `[my return data]`. They define an array.

Comment: nothing showing but console.log() is showing key value pair data

Comment: T.J Crosder I mean its showing any data with `[]`

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: There is no way you get anything looking like `[my return data]`. Tht isn't anything that json would send or get parsed. Show actual representation and don't make us guess at what you have

Comment: It's an object and exactly what it should look like. What were you expecting?

Comment: I need show string data. Just plain string.

Comment: then the answer below should output `sd` only

Comment: JSON is not html. It can contain html but you sent an asssociative array from php so I don't see why you would expect it to be html in the browser

Comment: how can I show this json return data to plain string @charlietfl ?

Comment: Using @madalinivascu answer ... it does what you want

Comment: May be I misunderstood you @charlietfl. I want to call ajax using json datatype and success data should be plain string. Like : your data has been successfully submited\

Comment: then you don't want json you want html response. Why are you sending an array if that's what you want? Why not send it the way it is and use answer below to display it? None of this is making any sense

Comment: It's a bit like saying I have some blue paint but why isn't the house turning red?

Comment: @charlietfl You don't understand my question

Comment: No...I don't think anyone does to be honest

Comment: Is it possible to pass json datatype to the php page and show plain string in the html page. I mean in ajax success method ?

Comment: Of course...the value of `key` is  a string....what exactly should be shown in page is value of key is `sd` which is a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the string, without wrapping it in an object, use

```
echo json_encode($key);
```

There's no need for the `$data` array.

However, returning an associative array allows for more flexible coding, as you can return multiple items. For instance, you can include a `status` key, so that the client can check whether the request was successful. With the way you're returning the data, you just need to change the Javascript code to do:

```
$("#filter_c_n_result").html(data.key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$("#filter_c_n_result").html(data.key);
```

if you want to return a message try the following:

```
$data['key'] = "Your data has been successfully submited";
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, May be I misunderstood you. All I need to show : plain string Just plain string.